# Twig function not loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

I use last version of Twig in Codeigniter project, I have an error I don't understand. I load my functions using Twig but I get this error :

> Message: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a
>   template ("Function () does not exist") in "base.twig".

To load my functions I use :

```
    foreach(get_defined_functions() as $functions) 
    {
        foreach($functions as $function) 
        {
            $this->_twig->addFunction( new \Twig_Function($function) );
        }
    }
```

Then in template I try :

```
{{ base_url('test') }}
```

I made a var_dump of **$twig->getFunctions()**, and **base_url()** is listed.

I just migrated to the last version of Twig, and got this error.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the way in Twig 2.2.4 :

```
    foreach(get_defined_functions() as $functions) 
    {
        foreach($functions as $function) 
        {
            $this->_twig->addFunction( new \Twig_SimpleFunction($function, $function) );
        }
    }
```

It works.